# inserting data into SQL Server does not work but there is no error message to show

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using asp.net 4.5 and SQL Server 2008 Express.

I want to insert a form's data into my database, connection string is OK and works in another page but in this page it seems the insert button just refreshes the page and no insert happened!

The code :

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        var cmdd = "insert into poroje (Pname,Pmozu,Ppayan,StartDate,EndTime,makan,tozih) values(@Pname,@Pmozu,@Ppayan,@StartDate,@EndTime,@makan,@tozih)";

        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdd, cnn))
            {
                if (aksporoje.HasFile)
                {
                    if (CheckFileType(aksporoje.FileName))
                    {
                       PersianCalendar Pe = new PersianCalendar();

                       string s = Pe.GetYear(System.DateTime.Now).ToString();

                       if (Directory.Exists("~/poroje/"+s))
                       {
                           Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/poroje/" + s+pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today)));
                           string filePath = "~/poroje/" + s + "/" + pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today) + "/" + aksporoje.FileName;
                           aksporoje.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));

                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aks","poroje/"+ s + "/" + pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today) + "/" + aksporoje.FileName);
                       }
                       else {
                           Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/poroje/"+s));
                           Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/poroje/"+s+ pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today)));
                           string filePath = "~/poroje/" + s + "/" + pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today) + "/" + aksporoje.FileName;
                           aksporoje.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));
                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aks", "poroje/" + s + "/" + pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today) + "/" + aksporoje.FileName);
                       }
                   }
                } 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pname", txtnam.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pmozu", txtmozu.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ppayan",false);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate",PersianDateTextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTime",null);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@makan", txtmakan.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tozih", txttozih.Text);

                try
                {
                    cnn.Open();

                    int recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    lblpeygham.Visible = true;
                    lblpeygham.Text = "error";
                }
                finally
                {
                    cnn.Close();
                    lblpeygham.Visible = true;
                    lblpeygham.Text = "data inserted";
                }
            }
        }
```

When I click on button the page refreshes amd the "data inserted" message is shown to me. But when I check the database nothing is inserted! Can you help me please?

Comment: Well, the "data inserted" always shows, because it's in the `finally` part of the code.

Comment: Did you debug your code and verify that recordsAffected is 1?

Comment: What's this `@aks` parameter you're adding? It's being added as a parameter to the command, but doesn't seem to be involved in the `INSERT` command at all.

Comment: Can you please show us the **connection string** you're using?

Comment: @marc_s     <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="workstation id=akhbarr.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=jujuee_SQLLogin_1;pwd=u9xyfsnev6;data source=akhbarr.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=akhbarr" />

Answer (score 0):

**The connection needs to be opened before the SQL COMMAND object is instantiated.**

I bet you the cnn.Open is wiping out any setting.

See this post for a correct working code at end.  Here is the correct order of events.

```
1 - Open connection object
2 - Declare string
3 - Open Command object
4 - Set parameters
5 - Call Execute Non SQL
6 - Close command object
7 - Close Connection object
```

[ASP.Net insert data from Textbox to a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509904/asp-net-insert-data-from-textbox-to-a-database)

Also, put a break point in the code, check the return values.

Good luck

J

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole SQL command into a string a run that directly on the server. What happens? Is the value added? if so then check the code again. That should help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is wrong..

```
int recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have never ran the command executeNonquery from an int before.. ever. It should be like

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Even then, I think you want everything in the try catch.. like this..

```
try
{
    cnn.Open();

    var cmdd = "insert into poroje (Pname,Pmozu,Ppayan,StartDate,EndTime,makan,tozih) values(@Pname,@Pmozu,@Ppayan,@StartDate,@EndTime,@makan,@tozih)";

    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdd, cnn))
        {
            if (aksporoje.HasFile)
            {
                if (CheckFileType(aksporoje.FileName))
                {
                   PersianCalendar Pe = new PersianCalendar();

                   string s = Pe.GetYear(System.DateTime.Now).ToString();

                   if (Directory.Exists("~/poroje/"+s))
                   {
                       Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/poroje/" + s+pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today)));
                       string filePath = "~/poroje/" + s + "/" + pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today) + "/" + aksporoje.FileName;
                       aksporoje.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));

                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aks","poroje/"+ s + "/" + pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today) + "/" + aksporoje.FileName);
                   }
                   else {
                       Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/poroje/"+s));
                       Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/poroje/"+s+ pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today)));
                       string filePath = "~/poroje/" + s + "/" + pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today) + "/" + aksporoje.FileName;
                       aksporoje.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aks", "poroje/" + s + "/" + pushePoroje(System.DateTime.Today) + "/" + aksporoje.FileName);
                   }
               }
            } 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pname", txtnam.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pmozu", txtmozu.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ppayan",false);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate",PersianDateTextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTime",null);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@makan", txtmakan.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tozih", txttozih.Text);


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                lblpeygham.Visible = true;
                lblpeygham.Text = "error";
            }
            finally
            {
                cnn.Close();
                lblpeygham.Visible = true;
                lblpeygham.Text = "data inserted";
            }
```

Something like that should work. But I think the main issue was the first mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all!
I change this part

```
 catch (SqlException)
            {
                lblpeygham.Visible = true;
                lblpeygham.Text = "error";
            }
```

to

```
 catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    lblpeygham.Visible = true;
                    lblpeygham.Text = ex.message;
                }
```

and understand that the startDate type in databse is dateTime but i was inserting nvarchar in it!
but now i hav a new problem. i want to create new folder with the Year name in host, but if I write

```
  Directory.CreateDirector("~/poroje/"+s);
```

the access deny error happen. and if i use

```
  Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/poroje/"+s));
```

there is no error but directory don't create!

Comment: If you have a new problem (and, especially, in this case, where it's not even closely related to your existing issue), ask a *new* question. Don't put follow up questions in an *answer* (They're unlikely to be answered)